# JS function join() { [native code] } in the output

Tags: javascript, xcode, join, native, codepen

when i click on the map i can see the right datas showed  but i see also function join() { [native code] }

here it is the code:
codepen.io/chicco-carto/pen/RwyeNmZ

what is wrong?

Comment: You have to call the function to use it `.join()`, not `.join`

Comment: i changed in datiqres.join() += item.nome +'<br>' //item.nome + '<br>' but with no success

Comment: You have another join later

Comment: changed also in codepen both join() and now disappeared the output

Answer (score 0):

a dirty solution can be:

```js
function func() {
  datiqres.join += item.nome +'<br>' 
  mostra = datiqres.join; 
} 
func();
        
//.replace() will remove the text from string
let mostra1 = mostra.replace('function join() { [native code] }','');
  
var sidebarContainer = document.querySelector('.sidebar-feature-content');
sidebarContainer.innerHTML =  '<div>'  + mostra1 + '</div>';
```